# Convert yyyyMMdd format to dd/MM/yyyy with Luxon library

Tags: javascript, angular, date, luxon, angular-spectator

I try to parse a date format like '20230701' to '01/07/2023' with Luxon library.

I can do this with the following code:

```
  toDateFormatDDMMYYYY = DateTime.fromFormat(
    dateFormatToTransform,
    'ddMMyyyy'
  ).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_SHORT);
```

`toDateFormatDDMMYYYY` has the good format (dd/MM/yyyy) when I `console.log()`. But this code make my jest spectator test fail:

```
  it('should transform date to format dd/MM/yyyy when BO format is yyyyMMdd', () => {
    spectator = createPipe(`{{'20201130' | formatDateToddMMyyyy}}`);
    expect(spectator.element).toHaveText('30/11/2020'); // KO returns invalid date
  });
```

I don’t know if it’s my code or my test that has a problem...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why even bother with a library? `let [c,y,m,d] = '20230701'.match(/\d\d/g)||[]; let date = \`${d}/${m}/${c}${y}\``.

Comment: it’s my lead tech  that makes me do it, I would do without

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a date string `20201130` that doesn't follow your defined format `ddMMyyyy`.

Either you change your format to `yyyyMMdd` or change the date string to `30112020`

```
const toDateFormatDDMMYYYY = DateTime.fromFormat(
  dateFormatToTransform,
  'yyyyMMdd'
).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_SHORT);
```

Comment: Sorry for asking a question due to my thoughtlessness... Thank you and your help